# PL/SQL procedure, %TYPE

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, plsqldeveloper

I have this task.
I did it but e need to use specific ID (`tmp_emp_id   EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE := 118;`) or its giving me an error. How I can tell "check every ID".

Write a PL/SQL procedure to update the salary of an employee, provided as a parameter, by 5% if the salary exceeds the mid range of the salary against this job and update up to mid range if the salary is less than the mid range of the salary.

```
DECLARE
  emp_min_salary NUMBER(6,0);
  emp_max_salary NUMBER(6,0);
  emp_mid_salary NUMBER(6,2);
  tmp_salary     EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
  tmp_emp_id     EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE := 118;
  tmp_emp_name   EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN

  SELECT min_salary,
         max_salary
  INTO emp_min_salary,
       emp_max_salary
  FROM JOBS
  WHERE JOB_ID = (SELECT JOB_ID
                 FROM EMPLOYEES
                 WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = tmp_emp_id);
 
  -- calculate mid-range
  emp_mid_salary := (emp_min_salary + emp_max_salary) / 2;
  -- get salary of the given employee
  SELECT salary,first_name
  INTO tmp_salary,tmp_emp_name
  FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id = tmp_emp_id;
 
  -- update salary 
  
  IF tmp_salary < emp_mid_salary THEN
    UPDATE employees
    SET salary = emp_mid_salary
    WHERE employee_id = tmp_emp_id;
  ELSE
    UPDATE employees
    SET salary = salary + salary * 5 /100
    WHERE employee_id = tmp_emp_id;
  END IF;
   --display message
  IF tmp_salary > emp_mid_salary THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The employee '||tmp_emp_name||' ID ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_emp_id) ||
                         ' works in salary ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_salary) ||
                         ' which is higher than mid-range of salary ' || TO_CHAR(emp_mid_salary));
  ELSIF tmp_salary < emp_mid_salary THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The employee '||tmp_emp_name||' ID ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_emp_id) ||
                         ' works in salary ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_salary) ||
                         ' which is lower than mid-range of salary ' || TO_CHAR(emp_mid_salary));
 
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The employee '||tmp_emp_name||' ID ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_emp_id) ||
                         ' works in salary ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_salary) ||
                         ' which is equal to the mid-range of salary ' || TO_CHAR(emp_mid_salary));
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: "...  its giving me an error" - which error?

Comment: Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 10
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.

What I am doing is ```tmp_emp_id     EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE := 118;```  changing in to   ```tmp_emp_id     EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE ;``` and probably thats my mistake. should i do it with LOOP? so i can check every employee salary, but not only one specific

Comment: No loop; task says that employee ID is passed as a parameter to the procedure. Have a look at answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

`NO_DATA_FOUND` is returned by one of `SELECT` statements you used; can't tell which one, I don't have your data.

However, that can be simplified. Here's an example which shows how you might do that.

Sample data is based on Scott's EMP table.

Mid-salaries (using the same algorithm you used):

```
SQL>   SELECT job, (MIN (sal) + MAX (sal)) / 2 midsal
  2      FROM emp
  3  GROUP BY job;

JOB           MIDSAL
--------- ----------
CLERK           1050      --> I'll be using CLERKS for demonstration
SALESMAN        1425
PRESIDENT       5000
MANAGER       2712,5
ANALYST         3000
```

Clerks:

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM employees
  3     WHERE job = 'CLERK'
  4  ORDER BY ename;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
      7900 JAMES      CLERK            950
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300  --> salary is higher than mid-salary
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            800  --> salary is lower than mid-salary
```

Procedure: it uses `MERGE` as it does *everything* in the same step, no need for additional commands.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_sal (par_empno IN employees.empno%TYPE)
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4     MERGE INTO employees e
  5          USING (  SELECT job, (MIN (sal) + MAX (sal)) / 2 midsal
  6                     FROM emp
  7                 GROUP BY job) x
  8             ON (e.job = x.job)
  9     WHEN MATCHED
 10     THEN
 11        UPDATE SET
 12           e.sal =
 13              CASE WHEN e.sal > x.midsal THEN e.sal * 1.05 ELSE x.midsal END
 14                WHERE e.empno = par_empno;
 15  END;
 16  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> EXEC p_sal(7369);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC p_sal(7934);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM employees
  3     WHERE job = 'CLERK'
  4  ORDER BY ename;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
      7900 JAMES      CLERK            950
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1365  --> 5% raise
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           1050  --> set to mid-salary

SQL>
```

Comment: I am connected to HR

Answer (score 0):

Personally I voted the solution of @littlefoot, since he answered properly about the original question of the NO_DATA_FOUND and also shrinked the code in 1 single merge statement as I would too.

I just want to add an alternate version in case you "need" to log salary changes and/or add more business logic for each specific case.

```
    DECLARE
      emp_mid_salary NUMBER(6,2);
      tmp_salary     EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
      new_salary     EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
      tmp_emp_id     EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE := 118;
      tmp_emp_name   EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
    BEGIN
      --single query for extract all data
      SELECT (min_salary + max_salary) / 2, salary, first_name
      INTO emp_mid_salary, tmp_salary, tmp_emp_name
      FROM JOBS J
      JOIN EMPLOYEES E
        ON J.JOB_ID = E.JOB_ID
      WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID = tmp_emp_id
      ;
      --business logic
      IF tmp_salary > emp_mid_salary THEN
        --calcs
        new_salary := tmp_salary + tmp_salary * 5 /100;
        --output
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The employee '||tmp_emp_name||' ID ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_emp_id) ||
                             ' works in salary ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_salary) ||
                             ' which is higher than mid-range of salary ' || TO_CHAR(emp_mid_salary));
      ELSIF tmp_salary < emp_mid_salary THEN
        --calcs
        new_salary := emp_mid_salary;
        --output
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The employee '||tmp_emp_name||' ID ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_emp_id) ||
                             ' works in salary ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_salary) ||
                             ' which is lower than mid-range of salary ' || TO_CHAR(emp_mid_salary));
     
      ELSE
        --calcs
        new_salary := tmp_salary + tmp_salary * 5 /100;
        --output
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The employee '||tmp_emp_name||' ID ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_emp_id) ||
                             ' works in salary ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_salary) ||
                             ' which is equal to the mid-range of salary ' || TO_CHAR(emp_mid_salary));
      END IF;
      BEGIN
          --one single final update
          UPDATE employees
          SET salary = new_salary
          WHERE employee_id = tmp_emp_id;
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Failed to update salary to employee with ID ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_emp_id));
            --handle/log exception
      END;
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Could not find a JOB related to the employee with ID ' || TO_CHAR(tmp_emp_id));
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            --handle/log exception, in the rare case something went wrong with the calcs?
    END;
    /
```